# Thickening Eggs with Cornstarch

Tags: eggs, thickening, cornstarch

Recently I stumbled across a recipe that uses corn starch to thicken scrambled eggs and was wondering if there was any advice on tweaking the recipe to try and keep the calorie count down.

3 Large eggs
1 1/2 tbs whole milk (I use 2%) - 1/2 tbsp per egg
1 3/4 tsp potato starch or cornstarch (I use cornstarch) -- 5/8 tsp per egg
3 tbs unsalted butter (I use half that) -- 1 tbs per egg

Not in the recipe but I also add 1/2 tps of garlic when making it

This ends up being a quick way to make some good eggs but want to make it more healthy if possible.

Comment: Link to original recipe: http://ladyandpups.com/2015/02/03/magic-15-seconds-creamy-scrambled-eggs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the estimated calories in that recipe:

- Eggs: 270
- Milk: 12
- Cornstarch: 15
- Butter: 306

So, given that the single largest source of calories in that recipe is the butter -- more than the eggs! -- if you're looking to reduce calorie count cutting back on the butter to 1 Tbs is the way to go.   Of course, that will affect the flavor as well.  The cornstarch isn't significant in those quantities.

(calorie counts are via Google, but are consistent with what I've seen elsewhere)

My personal perspective is: if you're looking to reduce calories, simply eat less. Compromising flavor in order to save calories is pointless; just make delicious foods in very small quantities.